# Node REPL: how to break out of ...?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, freeze

So, in the node REPL, if I do something stupid, I get stuck in ... hell. I suppose the interpreter is waiting for the statement to be closed, but how can I break out of this?

```
$ node
> "I did something stupid
...
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js REPL continuation lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734712/node-js-repl-continuation-lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do Ctrl-C and that works fine atleast in Linux .

Ctrl-C and Escape are the most common "break from something" keys .

It works in most of the terminal apps .

As a bonus , in linux I use Ctrl-L to clear Node.js, Python etc REPL .

It is helpful sometimes .

Comment: you can use `process.exit()` as well. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21794914/4708072

Answer (score 1):

You can type in `.exit` to exit the node.js REPL

Comment: You can also type `.break` to only break out of ... and stay in the REPL.

Comment: Lol what? This works but why???